# How to redirect if JavaScript is disabled in ASP.NET mvc masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a masterpage on which I want to check if user has disabled its JavaScript then redirect to a simple `error.aspx` page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Masterpage just add this code

```
<noscript>
<% Response.Redirect(Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")); %>
</noscript>
```

If user disabled the javascript it will redirect to specific controller action.

Comment: This is not a very good solution if your redirect page inherits from your master. Because the <noscript> will run even on the page you're redirecting to, causing the page to load repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to approach this problem is to redirect a user who has javascript *enabled* and display the error for the user who has it *disabled* using the `noscript` tag.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     location.href = 'pagethatneedsjavascript.aspx';
 </script>
 <noscript>
     This page needs JavaScript enabled!
 </noscript>
```

Alternatively if your page isn't the first page the user would load in the current session, you could add a link to the page like

```
<a href="/linktopage.aspx?js=disabled"
onclick="location.href='/linktopage.aspx?js=enabled';return false;">the page</a>
```

If the user has javascript disabled, they'll go to the page referenced in the `href` attribute, if they have it enabled the JavaScript in the `onclick` attribute will be executed instead.

You can then on the server side read the querystring variable and redirect if it equals "disabled"

```
if ( Request.QueryString["js"] == "disabled" ) {
    Response.Redirect("error.aspx");
}
```

Note that if the page is bookmarkable the user might end up on the page using js=enabled without js actually being enabled.